# When I turn my PowerPoint into a PDF, my clickable that should appear & disappear does not work. the info appears without being click

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm having some problem with my clickable "button" that I have in my presentation.

My presentation is 100+ page and I don't know if that's the problem or the problem occur when it's turn into a PDF.

My "button" are supped to work like this you click the # or letter and information about that # or letter should appear and when click again it should disappear.

It does work in the PowerPoint app but it doesn't in a PDF, all the information is shown.

I really need this to work, if there is another way for this please let me know.

If there's not another way, how can I make this work with the

animations > appear > Tigger > add animations > disappear > Tigger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKU1Y.png)